# First page of crystal report is blank

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I am making an application in Visual Studio 2005 to display data on crystal report. 
I have grouped the elements on the basis of Vendor Number.
I have two problems here.

First is the first page of Crystal Report is coming blank. It is showing only column names, date and page number. But data is displayed from second page.

[http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/9165/erru.jpg</a&gt;](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/9165/erru.jpg</a>)[^]

And my second problem is I want to display Vendor name in the place of Vendor Code as a page title.
And both the vendor code and vendor name are in different databases. So I will have to write a query for this. So, how to do it.

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Please check the page size setup.

Answer (score 0):

In your group properties, uncheck the option to 'Keep Group Together'. Since the group data does not fit on the same page, in order to prevent the group from being split the whole group is being moved to a new page.

As for the Vendor name fetching, you have to change your SQL query to join the Vendor table (along with database name [DBName.VendorTable]) using VendorCode as the foreign key and retrieve the Vendor name from that table.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arun has noted uncheck the "Group Together" option. Also check you have not checked 'New Page Before/After' in the Report header section

Comment: I have checked 'New page after'